# DDD: delete tree "Node" should check for children

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have a tree of Installations: Aggregate Installation has a property ParentInstallationId.

I also have a RemoveInstallationCommand --> repo.GetInstallation(x).Remove()

Now, I want to throw a domain error if I receive a RemoveInstallationCommand for an Installation that has children. But, the Installation aggregate doesnt know about its children, its the other way around.

So, is it ok to query the command model for children, and throw if count > 0?

If not, how would you solve this?

Answer (score 3):

The root of the problem here is the misunderstanding that an aggregate is somehow able to "remove" itself. Can an `Installation` "add" itself? You are missing a concept:

```
// within RemoveInstallationCommandHandler

var wizard = wizards.Find(cmd.InstallationId);

wizard.RemoveInstallation(); // could throw

wizards.Save(wizard);
```

Above we have the concept of an `InstallationWizard` that "knows" about a given `Installation` *and* all of it's children (and possibly any other dependencies). This makes it the ideal place to both add and remove installations as it is privy to all of the information necessary to coordinate the above activities.

The broader message here is that domain objects do not just appear/disappear! Especially if there are domain rules mediating either process.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your idea correctly then what you currently aiming is something like this:

```
var installation = repo.GetInstallation(id);
var installationChildren = repo.GetChildren(id);

if(installationChildren.Any()){
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
else{           
    installation.Remove();
}
```

So you make a query and based on result you make a decision.

Aggregate represents boundary of consistency.
If you say that Installation is an aggregate, but it doesn't know about its children,
then those children are out of your aggregate boundary.

Problem is that in order to preserve consistency in that 'Remove' operation, those children need to be part of your aggregate.

```
var installationRoot = repo.GetInstallation(id);
installationRoot.Remove();

class InstallationRoot {
    private List<Installation> children = new List<Installation>();
    private bool isRemoved = false;

    void Remove(){
        if(children.Any()){
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        else{
            isRemoved = true;
        }
    }
}
```

If you decide not to redraw your aggregate boundaries (which might be quite difficult in first place) then you risk with situation like:

```
// Joe attempts to 'Remove' installation
// Installation doesn't have any children at this point
var installation = repo.GetInstallation(id);
var installationChildren = repo.GetChildren(id);

if(installationChildren.Any()){
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
else{           
    // Meanwhile new nodes(children) are added by Jane
    installation.Remove();
    //Now you have orphans
}
```

If consistency is needed, then only way to preserve it is to redraw the boundary.
How? It depends how it is currently implemented.

Comment: Redrawing aggregate boundaries just moves the problem to another place. In the current form, I have a problem with deleting a parent who doesnt know about its children. If I add a "list of children IDs" to it, I will need to update 2 aggregates when creating a child (1: the new child 2: the parent's childID list). So, both soluitions need to violate boundaries.

Comment: `I will need to update 2 aggregates when creating a child.` 
What I meant by redrawing those boundaries is that at the end you have one aggregate with installation root and all its children.  

In the example of `InstallationRoot` where there is a list of children, it is not just a piece of code per se, but a emphasis on the need to load and save the Installation (as aggregate root) with all the children.  

What is your current persistence implementation of installations and children? Separate db-s? Relational? Streams?
Perhaps I can clarify if I were to know it.

Comment: It's worth noting here that *both* of the above examples could result in orphans. The *process* of removing an `Installation` cannot happen instantly, so concurrency (e.g. adding a child to the `Installation` while the removal process is running) is of course possible (save employing locking mechanisms).

Comment: I use optimisitic locks and a status. Pre-deletion you save the record back to the database in a "uninstalling" state. Now Jane knows this is being cleaned up, and cannot add her piece by setting the state to "installing". The optimisitic lock uses a date field to ensure you are moving from the first state to your next state without overwriting someone else's updates.